# monorepo with top level util imports

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to set up a rust repo that has top level directories like

dir1
dir2
dir3
shared

where dir1, dir2 and dir3 can all have their own /src/main.rs that can be run seperatly

I want some shared functionality within the shared folder, something like

shared/src/utils.rs

where I can define some utility functions that are shared across all the other top level directories, how could I accomplish this?

I've tried with creating a module and or a crate but I cant get it to work